# The best way to update existing Paragraphs in Production with newField = TRUE

Tags: paragraphs

how are you?

Do you know what's the best way to fill a new field inside of Paragraphs in a Production Environment?

E.g.:

1. I have a Paragraph called "MyParagraph" and this Paragraph has two fields "Title" and "Description";
2. This Paragraph is already present on our Production Environment and there are 500 nodes with this Paragraph filled;
3. I created right now a new field called "Show Description". This field is a checkbox and default is "Checked";

Now I need to update all of these 50 Paragraphs in production with this new field "Show Description" = TRUE

Do you know what's the best option to do that?

I used a simple hook_update to do this, and another script with a batch process.
But I want to see if there is the best solution to do this update.

Comment: hook_update_N already comes with batch capabilities. But 50 Paragraphs isn't that much. I doubt that this needs a batch process. When you ask for "best" you'll get opinions, not a right answer. I think hook_update_N is best.

Comment: Other option is to use views bulk operations.

Comment: Or just open 50 tabs and update them manually. 

Comment: I used ”50” just as an example. There are more than 500 to update.

Comment: @No-Sssweat I didn’t used views build operations before. Using it I can update all paragraphs by CMS that's it? 

Answer (score 0):

For a no custom code solution, Use Views Bulk Operations with [Views Update Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/bulk_update_fields)

Or with [Views Bulk Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_edit), although it's crashing with Paragraphs, so maybe in the future for this particular  case.

PS: Do first a dry run on dev/local before doing it on live.